# How to convert a plpgsql if-then-else function into an SQL one in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, common-table-expression

This is a very general doubt about how to convert a `plpgsql` function that starts with a `if-then-else` conditional clause into an SQL one.

The general structure could be this:

```sql
create or replace function f (
  _condition boolean default true
)
returns table (...)
stable language plpgsql as $$
begin
  -- perform the corresponding query depending on the conditional value
  if _condition then
    return query
    select something ...
  else
    return query
    select some other thing...
  end if;
end;
$$;
```

And a second variant could be this one:

```sql
create or replace function f ()
returns table (...)
stable language plpgsql as $$
declare
  _condition boolean;
begin
  -- calculate the conditional value
  select ... into _condition ...;

  -- perform the corresponding query depending on the conditional value
  if _condition then
    return query
    select something ...
  else
    return query
    select some other thing...
  end if;
end;
$$;
```

A CTE could be a good solution in both cases to hold the conditional value, but I do not find a way of executing the corresponding `select` in the execution part of the CTE.

I have seen SQL Server has `iif` and `cast` conditional operators, so maybe something similar can be possible in PostgreSQL.

Notice that both selects must return the same set of columns, as declared at `table (...)` however, the `from`, `where`, `order by` or/and `group by` clauses might be completely different.

Any idea?

Comment: Typically the equivalent of the non-standard `iif()` functions is the standard compliant `CASE` expression. But neither can be used to run different _queries_  inside another query. Both are expressions that return a single value based on one (or multiple) conditions.

Comment: I have managed to use `case` to switch between two different `where` clauses but not sure how to use it in the `from` clause

Comment: As I wrote: you can't use a CASE expression in SQL to "switch" between tables. It always returns a single **value**.

Comment: `return query
    select something ...
  else
    return query
    select some other thing...` <<-- something and someOtheThing **must** be UNION-compatible, so you can just use an `UNION`. (and: *please* don't use pseudocode)

Comment: You mean including _condition in both queries, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems a very good solution. Thanks!